# Usage of as_json and dynamic method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an simple class (without Rails)

```
class Tax

  attr_reader :guest_age

  def initialize(guest_age)
    @guest_age = guest_age
  end

  def amount
    0
  end

end
```

This object has an "amount" custom method
and I want to include the amount result in the json when I do this : `tax.as_json(methods: :amount)`

But this is not working, this return only the object with variables.

What I'm getting now :

> { "guest_age": 18 }

What I am expecting is :

> { "guest_age": 18, "amount": 0 }

See https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON/as_json

**Note :**

I want to keep this object without active record library dependency.

Comment: What's your Rails version?

Answer (score 5):

Tested with Rails 5.2.2, this is the source of `as_json`:

```
def as_json(options = nil) #:nodoc:
  if respond_to?(:to_hash)
    to_hash.as_json(options)
  else
    instance_values.as_json(options)
  end
end
```

Which means that if you implement a `to_hash` method in your class, your `as_json` call will work the way you wish:

```
class Tax

  attr_reader :guest_age

  def initialize(guest_age)
    @guest_age = guest_age
  end

  def amount
    0
  end

  def to_hash
    instance_values.merge(amount: amount)
  end
end
```

And...

```
Tax.new(1).as_json
# => {"guest_age"=>1, "amount"=>0}
```

This will include the `amount` always though, there does not seem to be an easy way around that.

It can work differently though, you need to explicitly throw away the `amount`:

```
Tax.new(1).as_json(except: :amount)
# => {"guest_age"=>1}
```

Or explicitly specify the attributes you wish to be serialized:

```
Tax.new(1).as_json(only: "guest_age")
# => {"guest_age"=>1}
```

The `methods` option that you'd like to use seems to be strictly tied to ActiveRecord.

Answer (score 2):

Can you define a custom method in your class?

```
  def to_h
    {guest_age: @guest_age, amount: amount}
  end
```

So you can call:

```
tax = Tax.new(18)
p tax.to_h
#=> {:guest_age=>18, :amount=>0}
```

Or

```
require 'json'
puts tax.to_h.to_json
#=> {"guest_age":18,"amount":0}
```

Comment: Conventionally called `to_h`.

Comment: @Xero, I did not tested it, but maybe you can convert the method `amount` to an instance variable `@amount`?

Comment: What's wrong with this approach? It works, even if it's a bit more verbose. I tried hacking around with `as_json` but bare Ruby doesn't support this as well as Rails does.

Answer (score 1):

the method option works for active model object.

```
class Tax

  include ActiveModel::Serialization
  include ActiveModel::Serializers::JSON

  attr_accessor :guest_age

  def initialize(guest_age)
    @guest_age = guest_age
  end

  def attributes
    {'guest_age' => nil}
  end

  def amount
    0
  end

end
```

code like this should work, for more info see the source code.

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activemodel/lib/active_model/serialization.rb

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activemodel/lib/active_model/serializers/json.rb